# Application logs heroku app crashed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, npm, react-router

I have a problem with an application in heroku. Could someone help me with this log?

> 2018-07-26T08:40:49.427912+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! myreads@1.0.1 start: `react-scripts start`
>
> 2018-07-26T08:40:49.428082+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
>
> 2018-07-26T08:40:49.428347+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
>
> 2018-07-26T08:40:49.428831+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the myreads@1.0.1 start script.
>
> 2018-07-26T08:40:49.429027+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> 2018-07-26T08:40:49.436775+00:00 app[web.1]:
>
> 2018-07-26T08:40:49.437011+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>
> 2018-07-26T08:40:49.437188+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-07-26T08_40_49_430Z-debug.log
>
> 2018-07-26T11:56:02.600061+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=my-books-reads.herokuapp.com request_id=6ebca156-9e51-4be5-817e-8d85c3d49dcd fwd="177.107.242.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
>
> 2018-07-26T11:56:03.098985+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=my-books-reads.herokuapp.com request_id=b8af4900-60a2-4edf-a4db-2113e9cddaec fwd="177.107.242.1" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you are hardcoding your port number ?
if it so then try below code

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Or run below command

```
heroku restart
```

Comment: My code is like this
exports.port = process.env.PORT || 3001

app.listen(config.port, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on port %s, Ctrl+C to stop', config.port)
})

Comment: Have you declared port number anywhere else in your app like config file ?

Answer (score 0):

react-scripts is by default a devDependency for CRA apps, but Heroku Node buildpack has environment NODE_ENV=production which causes npm install to skip devDependencies.

To install those devDependencies too:

Add this script to your package.json:
`"heroku-postbuild": "npm install --only=dev"`

Give this a trial, I feel it should solve the issue